# looking for a more elegant solution to this

Tags: python

> Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.
>
> ```
> sum67([1, 2, 2]) ? 5
> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) ? 5
> sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) ? 4
> ```

```
def sum67(nums):
    dontadd = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if dontadd == 0:
            if nums[i] == 6:
                dontadd = 1
            else:
                sum += nums[i]
        else:
            if nums[i] == 7:
                dontadd = 0
            else:
                pass# nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically
    return sum
```

Looking for a more elegant solution to this problem from codingbat.  This answer doesn't seem as intuitive as it could be

Comment: Questions like this belong either on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want general improvements, or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ if you want to see other solutions to the "puzzle"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for recommendations on a "more elegant" solution to working code, it should be on codereview at best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we can just remove the elements that we don't want, then we can use a simple sum. Here is an example:

```
def sum67(nums):
    nums=nums[:]
    while 6 in nums:
        i=nums.index(6)
        j=nums.index(7,i)
        del nums[i:j+1]
    return sum(nums)
```

First, we use `nums=nums[:]` to make a copy. The caller probably isn't expecting `nums` to change.

`nums.index(6)` finds the index of the first element that has a value of 6.  `nums.index(7,i)` finds the index of the first element that has a value of 7 after the index `i`. `del nums[i:j+1]` then deletes the elements in the range from `i` to `j`, including the element at `j`.

Comment: This seems like a strict improvement on my method of using pop.

Comment: Can you expain what j=nums.index(7,i) does? I don't rerally understand.

Comment: @MyCarta: I added some explanation to the answer. Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: +1 that explains it thank you. I was confused because all I knew was the string method string1.index(string2,begin,end)

Comment: I like Vaughn's other solution a lot better.  It doesn't make a copy of the list or anything, just sums in a loop, using `index` to skip to the next `7` after finding a `6`.  IDK if python interpreters / JIT-compilers are smart enough to see through what's going on here and not actually copy elements around in the array every iteration of the deletion loop.  And also to start the search from `i`, instead of from `0` every time.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't too bad (you might argue it's trying to be too clever though).

```
>>> def sum67(nums):
...     while 6 in nums:
...         index = nums.index(6)
...         while nums.pop(index) != 7:
...             pass
...     return sum(nums)
... 
>>> sum67([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7])
5
>>> sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2])
4
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7, 8, 1, 6, 0, -1000, 7, 2])
16
```

Here's a really goofy one(will not work with negative numbers)

```
>>> import re
>>> def sum67(nums):
...     return sum(int(j) for j in re.sub(r'6\d*?7', '', ''.join((str(i) for i in nums))))
>>> sum67([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7])
5
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7, 8, 1, 6, 0, 7, 2])
16
```

Please don't ever write code like that :p

One more awful one liner before I leave this alone:

```
>>> def sum67(nums):
...     return sum(i if i != 6 else -sum(nums[pos+1:nums.index(7,pos)+1]) for pos, i in enumerate(nums))
... 
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7])
5
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7, 8, 1, 6, 0, -1000, 7, 2])
16
```

Comment: This modifies the original list but it works nice. Thanks for exposing me to some new `list` methods!

Comment: @MarkRansom If you didn't want to modify the original list you'd put `nums = nums[:]` or something at the start of the method.  That's a good point actually, I hadn't really thought about the problem of changing the list.

Answer (score 3):

The thing I like most about Python is that it makes it so easy to break a problem apart.

```
def skip67(seq):
    skipping = False
    for value in seq:
        skipping = skipping or value == 6
        yield 0 if skipping else value
        skipping = skipping and value != 7

def sum67(seq):
    return sum(skip67(seq))

>>> sum67([1, 2, 2])
5
>>> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7])
5
>>> sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2])
4
```

Comment: There is no real need to yield up a 0 value.  You can make that second line in the `for` loop just be `if not skipping: yield value`  Aside from the nitpick, I like it.  Especially I like that this solution works with iterators, without forcing an intermediate list!

Comment: @steveha, I considered that. I kind of liked that the input and output sequences were the same length, but in the end it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum67(nums):
  i=0
  sum=0
  n=len(nums)
  while i<n:
    if nums[i]==6:
      i=nums.index(7,i)
    else:
      sum += nums[i]
    i+=1
  return sum
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum67(L):
    it = iter(L)
    return sum(all(i!=7 for i in it) if i == 6 else i for i in it)
```

A slightly more readable version if you're interested in how this works:

```
def slice67(L):
    it = iter(L)

    for i in it:
        if i != 6:
            yield i
        else:
            while next(it, 7) != 7:
                pass

print sum(slice67([1, 2, 2]))
```

Comment: +1 This is awesome but you can remove the `and 0` as the OP said that every 6 is matched by a 7.

Answer (score 1):

This version does not modify the list.

```
def sum67(xs):
  xs = iter(xs)
  s = 0
  for x in xs:
    if x == 6:
      while x != 7:
          x = xs.next()
    else:
      s += x
  return s
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution wouldn't be too different from the OP, but in general I like the idea of always having the add operation there and just having logic to switch the value of "accum" between 1 and 0.

```
def sum67(nbrs):
    total = 0
    accum = 1
    for nbr in nbrs:
        if nbr==6:
            accum=0
        total += nbr*accum
        if accum==0 and nbr==7:
            accum=1
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that may be simpler to understand:

```
def sum67(nums):
    found6 = False
    result = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n==6:
            found6 = True
            continue
        if n==7 and found6:
            found6 = False
            continue
        if not found6:
            result += n
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> def sum67(l):
...     sum = 0
...     add = True
...     for i in l:
...         add = add and (i != 6)
...         sum += add and i or 0
...         add = add or i == 7
...     return sum
... 
>>> print sum67([1, 2, 3]) 
6
>>> print sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) 
5
>>> print sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) 
4
>>> print sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7, 8, 1, 6, 0, -1000, 7, 2])
16
```

It takes advantage of the fact that Python evaluates Boolean expressions to the value of first operand that determines the result, e.g., in `sum += add and i or 0`, if `add` is `False`, it enters the `or` part and evaluates to `0`, if `add` were `True`, it would evaluate to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum67(nums):
  while 6 in nums:
    for x in nums[nums.index(6):]:
      nums.remove(x)
      if x == 7:
        break
  return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with list comprehension:

`def sum67(nums):
  return sum([x for index, x in enumerate(nums) if (((nums[(index - nums[index::-1].index(6)):].index(7) + (index - nums[index::-1].index(6))) < index) if (6 in nums[:index+1]) else True)])`