# Sum of numbers in array, not counting 13 and number directly after it (CodingBat puzzle)

Tags: python, list

**The Question:**

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

**My Code:**

```
def sum13(nums):
  l = len(nums)
  tot = 0

  if l==0:
    return 0

  for x in range(l):
    if nums[x]!=13:
      if nums[x-1]!=13:
        tot+=nums[x]

  return tot
```

**Where It's Failing:**

```
sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) should → 6, but my code is outputting 5
sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) should → 4, but my code is outputting 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is when `x` is zero. `x - 1` will be `-1` so it will get the last element of your list (`13`). To fix it, don't test `x - 1` if `x` is zero:

```
if x == 0 or nums[x-1] != 13:
```

In Python, when you pass a negative index to a list it accesses its elements backwards, so:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x[-1]
5
>>> x[-2]
4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's been driving me nuts! I'll accept the answer as soon as the time limit passes!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
def sum13(nums):

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 13:
            nums[i] = 0
            if i+1 < len(nums): 
                nums[i+1] = 0
    return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate()` can give the index, then it can be done using a generator expression in `sum()`.  The extra 0 added to the end of the list makes it work for `nums[i-1]` when `i = 0`.

```
def sum13(nums):
   nums += [0]
   return sum(n for i, n in enumerate(nums) if n != 13 and nums[i-1] != 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the bug by using `next()` function instead of error-prone indexes:

```
def exclude13(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in it:
        if x == 13: # don't yield 13
           next(it) # skip number immediately after 13
        else:
           yield x

print(sum(exclude13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]))) # -> 6
print(sum(exclude13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]))) # -> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control over how the function is called b/c it is on CodingBat.com, but either way, thanks for the tip!

Comment: you could easily define the function: `sum13 = lambda L: sum(exclude13(L))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum13(nums):
    count = 0
    while count < len(nums):
        if nums[count] == 13:
            del nums[count:count+2]
            continue
        count += 1
    return sum(nums)
```

Comment: Instead of deleting from the list, couldn't you just increment `count` an extra time?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum13(nums):
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
         if nums[i] == 13 or sum == 1 :
            nums[i]= 0
            sum = sum + 1
         count = count + nums[i]
         if sum  ==  2:
            sum  = 0
    if nums == []:
          return 0
    return coun
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum13(nums):
  if len(nums)==0:
    return 0
  sum=0
  for i in range(1,len(nums)):
    if nums[i]==13 or nums[i-1]==13:
      sum = sum
    else:
      sum += nums[i]
  if nums[0]==13:
    return sum
  else:
    return sum + nums[0]
```

Start the loop form 1 and add back the first number (if it's not 13) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the list so that the original doesn't change, remove instances of the number 13 and the number immediately following, then sum the resulting list:

```
def sum13(nums):
    nums = nums[:]
    while 13 in nums:
        i = nums.index(13)
        del nums[i:i+2]
    return sum(nums)
```

This is similar to the top answer for this problem:
[looking for a more elegant solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184714/looking-for-a-more-elegant-solution-to-this)

Answer (score 1):

```py
    def sum13(nums):
        sum = 0
        len_n = len(nums)
        k = 0
        while k < len_n:
            if nums[k] == 13:
                k += 2
            else:
                sum += nums[k]
                k += 1
        return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it:

```
def sum13(nums):
  sub = 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13 :
      sub+=nums[i]
      if i+1<len(nums) and nums[i+1]!=13:
        sub+=nums[i+1]

  return sum(nums)-sub
```

Answer (score 1):

sum of list except when `item=13` will not be counted and `item+1` also be not counted

```
def sum13(nums):
  if len(nums)==0:
    return 0
  if nums[-1]==13:
    nums[-1]=0
  for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i]==13:
      nums[i]=0
      nums[i+1]=0
  return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum13(nums):
  result = 0
  i = 0

  while i < len(nums):
    if nums[i] == 13:
      i += 2
      continue
    else:
      result += nums[i]
      i += 1

  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You're excluding numbers that come immediately *before* a 13 when you should be excluding numbers that come immediately *after*.

Comment: When x is 4, and nums[4]=7, I also need to check that nums[3] is not 13 (or the 7 wouldn't count), so I'm pretty sure that I'm checking the number that comes immediately after, but I could be missing something.

Comment: Right you are, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a recursive solution. Note that while index of a list can be out of range the slicing gives an empty list and not an error, e.g. if a = [1,1,2] then a[3] would give an error while a[3:] gives the empty list [].

```
def sum13(nums):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0
  sum = sum13(nums[1:])
  if nums[0] != 13:
    return sum + nums[0]
  if nums[0] == 13:
    return sum13(nums[2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the following fashion.  It is brute force, but it does work:

```
def sum13(nums):
    count = 0
    if len(nums) == 0: 
        return 0
    for ans in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[ans] == 13 and ans < len(nums)-1: 
            nums[ans] = 0
            nums[ans+1] = 0
        elif nums[ans] == 13 and ans == len(nums)-1:
            nums[ans] = 0 
        else: 
            count += nums[ans]

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
  nums2 = []
  if 13 in nums:
    for i in range(len(nums)-1): # the -1 is needed to avoid out of range.
      if nums[i] != 13: nums2.append(nums[i])
      else:
        nums[i] = 0
        nums[i+1] = 0
    return sum(nums2)
  return sum(nums)
```

I created a separate list and appended the figures i wanted into that list.
i did this through a for loops by going through every element and appending that figure if it did not equal 13.

when it did eventually equal the number 13 i would then change that number by setting it to zero (nums[i] = 0). Then I also need to set the next number to it at Zero by indexing (nums[i+1] = 0). so they are then discounted from the sum of the list.

this is not a perfect solution but it is a working one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach that i have taken,this works as well

```
nums = [1, 2, 2, 1, 13,2,1,2,3,13,4,5]
counter = 0
temp = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13:
        if (i+1) != len(nums) and nums[i+1] != 13:
            temp.append(nums[i+1])
            continue
        elif (i+1) == len(nums):
            continue
    else:
        counter = counter + nums[i]
temp_total = sum(temp)
count_total = counter - temp_total
print(count_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

When `x=0` in `nums[x-1]` it conflicts, because it results as `nums[0-1]` if it is 13 then it may not add so check `nums[0]` at last.

```py
def sum13(nums):
  co=0
  if len(nums)<=0:
    return co
  for a in range(1,len(nums)):
    if nums[a]==13:
      continue
    elif nums[a-1]==13:
      continue
    else:
      co=co+nums[a]      
  if nums[0]!=13:
    co+=nums[0]
  return co
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for this exercise!!!!

```
def sum13(nums):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if (nums[i] == 13 or nums[i-1] == 13 and i != 0):
            total = total
        else:
            total += nums[i]
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
    sum=0
    ind13=[]
    for num in nums:
        if num==13:
            num=0
            ind13=nums.index(13)
            ind13next=ind13+1
            nums[ind13]=0
            if nums[ind13] !=nums[-1]:
                nums[ind13next]=0
                sum=sum+num
        else:
            sum=sum+num
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):

  summed=0
  flag=True
  index_13=0

  for index, num in enumerate(nums):

    if num==13:
      index_13=index
      flag=False

    if flag==True:
      summed=summed+num

    if index_13+1<= len(nums)-1 and num==nums[index_13+1]:
       flag=True

  return summed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
    li=[]
    if nums[-1]==13:
        li.append(13)
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==13:    
            li.append(nums[i])
            li.append(nums[i+1])
    n=sum(nums)
    return (n-sum(li))
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

```
   def sum13(nums):
       nums += [0]
       add=sum(j for i, j in enumerate(nums) if j != 13 and nums[i-1] != 13)
       return add
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
  sum=0
  count=0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]!=13:
        count=count-1
        if count<=0:
            sum=sum+nums[i]
    else:
        count=2
  return sum
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/4733879) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about the problem lends me to loop over the list - except for the last element. Then if a value is 13, the next element becomes 0. From there - I reload the list - and replace ALL 13 with 0. In the end I simply sum the values of the list.

```
def sum13(nums):
for i,x in enumerate(range(len(nums)-1)):
    if (nums[x]==13):
        nums[i+1]=0
        nums=nums
for i,x in enumerate(nums):
    if x==13: #if the element is equal to 13
        nums[i]=0
return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well. Basically it's a double continue statement. You assign pairs of index and value for each iteration with enumerate(). If a number is == 13 --> continue, the next iterated item should qualify for the elif statement, which also continues for items preceded by a 13. Elif runs only for items at indices >= 1 (so there is no issue with going out of range at [0]).

```py
def sum13(nums):
  if nums ==[]:
    return 0
  sum = 0
  for index, val in enumerate(nums):
    if nums[index] == 13:
      continue
    elif nums[index-1] == 13 and index > 0:
      continue
    else:
      sum += val
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sum13(nums):

  total = sum(nums)

  for i in range (len(nums)):
    if nums[i]==13:
      total = total - nums[i]
      if (i+1) < len(nums) and nums[i+1]!=13: #Using !=13 because 13 will already
        total = total-nums[i+1]               #be detected from previous if

  return total
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't (just) intended to solve the immediate problem, but (also) to help future readers understand the solution so that they can apply it to similar problems, or come to better understand the code. Given that, please don't just post code. Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe this is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0
  total = 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13 and  (len(nums)-1)>i:
      nums[i+1]=0
      total = total
    elif nums[i]==13:
      total = total
    else:
      total = total +nums[i]
  return total
```

Comment: The question as about where the code is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

here another solution :

```
def sum13(nums):
  for i in range (len(nums)) :
    if nums[i] == 13 :
      nums[i] = 0 
      if i+1 < len(nums) and nums[i+1] != 13 :
        nums[i+1] = 0
        
  return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have tried:)

```
sum = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 13:
        if i+1 < len(a):
            a[i], a[i+1] = 0, 0
        else:
            a[i] = 0
    else:
        sum += a[i]
return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

There are serval ways:

1. Change the list item "13" and the one after "13". But this is a small problem, exp: [13,13,2,1]. The result should be 1, but this way will return 3 since it change the second "13" in the first run function For.
2. Sum the list except the "13" and the one after "13". I think it is the best solution:

`

```
def sum13_v3(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0
    a = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] != 13:
            a = a + nums[i]
            if i>0 and nums[i-1] == 13:
                a = a - nums[i]
    return a
```